# Typescript, check if object have all type properties

Tags: typescript

So i need a function that will check if a given argument have all of Command properties, but i don't want it look like

```js
        typeof obj['prop1'] === 'string' &&
        typeof obj['prop2'] === 'string' &&
        typeof obj['prop3'] === 'object' &&
```

there is code:

```js
type Command<DataPerGuildType> = {
  name: string;
  execute(message: Message, guildData: DataPerGuildType, args: string[]): Promise<void>;
};

const isCommand = <GuildDataType>(
  toCheck: object,
): toCheck is Command<GuildDataType> => {

  let result = true;
  
  Object.keys(Command<DataPerGuildType>).forEach(
    (key: string) => { if (!toCheck.hasOwnProperty(key)) result = false }
  ));

  return result;

};

(THIS CODE DOES NOT WORK, BECAUSE Object.keys() CANNOT RECEIVE ARGUMENT WITH TYPE "TYPE")

what can i do?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a schema validation library like [zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod).

```js
import { z } from "zod";

const Command = z.object({
  prop1: z.string(),
  prop2: z.string(),
  // ... etc
});

Command.parse(toCheck);
```